# ClassNotFoundException in a default Maven Java project

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

Since I have instlalled Netbeans 10 IDE, I cant't run my project outside this IDE. With Netbeans opened, everything is ok and no "ClassNotFoundException" message is displayed. Therefore, if I run the project outside IDE, a "ClassNotFoundException" message is thrown in console. This is a default Maven Jar Project running over Java 8 and my "pom.xml" is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br....</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>${project.build.finalName}.lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>br.....JFramePrincipal</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Output is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by outside the project? How are you running your application?

Comment: Executing the project via command line "...java -jar...."